# How to count spaces between columns

Tags: awk

How can I count the number of spaces *(16)* between `S1,` and `//` in the following line:

```
S1,                // name
```

Comment: With grep + wc: `| grep -o  " " | wc -l`

Comment: @fedorqui nice idea but you would count all the space on the line, see my answer for a tweaked version that solves that issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way:

```
awk -F '//' '{ n = gsub(/ /, "", $1); print n }'
```

Test:

```
echo 'S1,                // name' | awk -F '//' '{ n = gsub(/ /, "", $1); print n }'
```

Results:

```
16
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want `awk` then you can build on the following.

```
$ echo "S1,                // name" | awk '{x=gsub(/ /," ",$0); print x}'
17
```

`gsub` returns the number of replacements made. Obviously this regex will also find and count other spaces but you get the point.

Or try something like this:

```
echo "S1,                // name" | 
awk -F[,/] ' { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print "$"i " is \""$i"\" of length, " length($i);}'
```

#### Test:

```
$ echo "S1,                // name" | awk -F[,/] ' { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print "$"i " is \""$i"\" of length, " length($i);}'
$1 is "S1" of length, 2
$2 is "                " of length, 16
$3 is "" of length, 0
$4 is " name" of length, 5
```

Comment: woah downvoter, please comment if you felt the answer was wrong. I am learning too! :)

Comment: +1 I come up with the same: `awk -F/ '{print gsub(" ","x",$1)}'` your first line counts all spaces, not between `, and /`

Answer (score 1):

Count all spaces between `S1,` and `//` only with `awk`:

```
$ echo 'S1,                // name' | awk -F'[,/]' '{print length($2)}'
16
```

Or a method based off [**fedorqui**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui) comment:

```
$ echo 'S1,                // name' | grep -Po '(?<=S1,) *(?=//)' | wc -L 
16
```

Comment: +1 I was expecting your awk solution! My grep+wc was just an approach for the meanwhile :)

Answer (score 0):

Pure bash

```
x='S1,                // name'
x=${x#S1,}
x=${x%//*}
echo ${#x}
16
```